# Pandas - create new columns from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following series of hourly data:

```
timestamp
2021-01-04 00:00:00   32896.2200
2021-01-04 01:00:00   33229.4000
2021-01-04 02:00:00   33508.7800
2021-01-04 03:00:00   33611.6000
2021-01-04 04:00:00   33345.2500
                         ...    
2021-04-23 19:00:00   50963.6000
2021-04-23 20:00:00   50563.0000
2021-04-23 21:00:00   50361.3700
2021-04-23 22:00:00   50524.4600
2021-04-23 23:00:00   51187.2700
```

I want to create a dataframe which would have each week as a separate column with 168 (24 hours * 7 days a week) rows. What would be the most optimal way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating an extra column `week` with `dt.isocalendar().week`, and then creating a pivot table with weeks as columns. The only issue is how to handle the timestamps, as I can imagine you'd like to keep them as index. A solution would be to split the timestamps by `dt.dayofweek` and `dt.hour` and to use these as indexes:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ { "timestamp": "2021-01-04 00:00:00", "value": 32896.22 }, { "timestamp": "2021-01-04 01:00:00", "value": 33229.4 }, { "timestamp": "2021-01-04 02:00:00", "value": 33508.78 }, { "timestamp": "2021-01-04 03:00:00", "value": 33611.6 }, { "timestamp": "2021-01-04 04:00:00", "value": 33345.25 }, { "timestamp": "2021-04-23 19:00:00", "value": 50963.6 }, { "timestamp": "2021-04-23 20:00:00", "value": 50563 }, { "timestamp": "2021-04-23 21:00:00", "value": 50361.37 }, { "timestamp": "2021-04-23 22:00:00", "value": 50524.46 }, { "timestamp": "2021-04-23 23:00:00", "value": 51187.27 } ]
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['week'] = df['timestamp'].dt.isocalendar().week
df["day_of_week"] = df["timestamp"].dt.dayofweek
df["hour"] = df["timestamp"].dt.hour
final_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['day_of_week', 'hour'], columns=['week'])
```

This will result in:

|  | 1 | 16 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (0, 0) | 32896.2 | nan |
| (0, 1) | 33229.4 | nan |
| (0, 2) | 33508.8 | nan |
| (0, 3) | 33611.6 | nan |
| (0, 4) | 33345.2 | nan |
| (4, 19) | nan | 50963.6 |
| (4, 20) | nan | 50563 |
| (4, 21) | nan | 50361.4 |
| (4, 22) | nan | 50524.5 |
| (4, 23) | nan | 51187.3 |